# rsyslog: how do I set up remote logging?

Tags: centos, logs, remote, rsyslog

I am simply trying to set up a remote logging system. I think my setup is correct but it fails and I can't get any messages from rsyslog to show up in the logs, so I can't find out why. My iptables rules allow unrestricted access on port 514. I would also like to know in the future how I can get rsyslog to log to its own log file so I can find out.

I used the template shown on the redhat site:
server:

```
# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

$template TmplAuth "/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"

authpriv.* ?TmplAuth
*.info,mail.none,authpriv.none,cron.none ?TmplMsg
```

Client:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog # where to place spool files
$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
*.* @loghost:514
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

rsyslog.conf files are abbreviated to what I think is the relevant info. Thanks in advanced

Comment: You restarted rsyslog (remote + sever) after making the changes, right? Also which CentOS? Also restarted the firewall? Seems pretty straightforward in this tutorial: http://linuxsysconfig.com/2013/04/how-to-configure-remote-logging-on-rhel6-centos6/

Comment: I used: `:FROMHOST-IP, isequal, "1.1.1.1" /var/log/www.log` from your link and I got a log file to show up. Is this a requirement? This is the first blog to mention it. I'm glad I finally got something

Comment: For reference: http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/03/01/install-and-configure-rsyslog-on-rhel-6-centos-6/

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled syslog reception over TCP and UDP on the client, where it's not needed.

On the server you have only enabled TCP log reception, however generally in my experience mainly UDP is used. So enable UDP log reception on the server, and it should work.

Comment: I switched it. I'll play around some more But I can't find a configuration that works. I desperately need a way to get rsyslog to start spitting debug info or this will all be a waste.